# Java inheritance 9.1 MonetaryCoin

Tags: inheritance

> 9.1: MonetaryCoin Design and implement a class called MonetaryCoin that is derived from the Coin class presented in Chapter 5. Store an
>   integer in the MonetaryCoin that represents its value and add a method
>   that returns its value. Add a  toString method that appends a space
>   followed by the coin's value to the Coin's String representation.
>
> Driver. Instead of creating a main driver class, include a  main
>   method in the MonetaryCoin class itself to exercise the class's
>   behavior. Your method should create an array of 7 MonetaryCoin objects
>   with values 1,5,10,25,50,100,100 and then iterate through the array,
>   flipping in each coin. The method should then iterate through the
>   array again, invoking the getValue method and adding up the resulting
>   values. The String representation of each coin should then be printed
>   on a line by itself, followed by, on a line by itself, the sum of the
>   values that was computed (preceded by the label "Total Value: ".

That is the question, and so far my code I have entered is:

```
public class MonetaryCoin extends Coin


{ private int value; 
 public int getValue()
 { return value; } 
 public String toString() 
{ return super.toString() + " " + value; } 
public static void main(String [] args) 
{ int sum = 0;
MonetaryCoin[] coin = {1,5,10,25,50,100,100}; 
for(int i = 0;i<coin.length;i++)
 { coin[i].flip(); } 
for(int i = 0;i<coin.length;i++) 
{ sum += coin[i].getValue(); 
System.out.println(coin[i].toString()); } 
System.out.println(); 
System.out.println("Total Value: " + sum); } }
```

I receive an error response saying:

```
MonetaryCoin.java:9: incompatible types
found   : int
required: MonetaryCoin
MonetaryCoin[] coin = {1,5,10,25,50,100,100}; 
                       ^
MonetaryCoin.java:9: incompatible types
found   : int
required: MonetaryCoin
MonetaryCoin[] coin = {1,5,10,25,50,100,100}; 
                         ^
MonetaryCoin.java:9: incompatible types
found   : int
required: MonetaryCoin
MonetaryCoin[] coin = {1,5,10,25,50,100,100}; 
                           ^
MonetaryCoin.java:9: incompatible types
found   : int
required: MonetaryCoin
MonetaryCoin[] coin = {1,5,10,25,50,100,100}; 
                              ^
MonetaryCoin.java:9: incompatible types
found   : int
required: MonetaryCoin
MonetaryCoin[] coin = {1,5,10,25,50,100,100}; 
                                 ^
MonetaryCoin.java:9: incompatible types
found   : int
required: MonetaryCoin
MonetaryCoin[] coin = {1,5,10,25,50,100,100}; 
                                    ^
MonetaryCoin.java:9: incompatible types
found   : int
required: MonetaryCoin
MonetaryCoin[] coin = {1,5,10,25,50,100,100};
```

How can I get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to assign an array of ints to what you've defined as an array of objects.

Comment: how could I go about making it an int array instead?